# C# Additional information: Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#

I have got some code: THE FULL

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Windows;
            using System.Windows.Controls;
            using System.Windows.Data;
            using System.Windows.Documents;
            using System.Windows.Input;
            using System.Windows.Media;
            using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
            using System.Windows.Navigation;
            using System.Windows.Shapes;
            using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

            namespace mysql
            {
                /// <summary>
                /// Interaction logic for LoginPage.xaml
                /// </summary>
                public partial class LoginPage : Page
                {
                    private string conn;
                    private MySqlConnection connect;

                    AdminPage ap = new AdminPage();

                    public LoginPage()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    private void db_connection()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn = "Server=localhost;Database=student;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;";
                            connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                            connect.Open();
                        }
                        catch (MySqlException e)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

                    private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
                    {
                        db_connection();
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from student.admins where username=@user and password=@pass";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                        cmd.Connection = connect;
                        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (login.Read())
                        {
                            connect.Close();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            connect.Close();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    private void btn_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        string user = txt_admin_name.Text;
                        string pass = txt_admin_passwd.Password;
                        if (user == "" || pass == "")
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
                            txt_errormessage.Text = "Empty Fields Detected! Please fill up all the fields!";
                            return;
                        }
                        bool r = validate_login(user, pass);
                        if (r)
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show("Correct Login Credentials.\n You will be taken the Admin Page!");
                            this.NavigationService.Navigate(ap);
                        }
                        else
                            //MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login Credentials");
                            txt_errormessage.Text = "Incorrect Login Credentials!";
                    }
                }
            }
```

So i need to some error handling: Check the server connection, and check  existence of database. I would like to write MessageBox.

I tried but...
 "Additional information: Connection must be valid and open."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm assuming you have declared conn and connect somewhere else we cannot see, because I don't see their declarations anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to use a connection to a database for every kind of task it is always a good practice to follow the pattern CREATE/OPEN/USE/CLOSE/DISPOSE

So your db_connection code should return the connection created and opened and never use a global variable to keep the connection instance.

```
private MySqlConnection db_connection()
{
    try
    {
        conn = "Server=localhost;Database=student;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;";
        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        cnn.Open();
        return cnn;
    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0: MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server!"); break;
        }
        retur null;
    }
}
```

Now the code that want to use your method could be written in a more resource friendly way

```
private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
{
    using(MySqlConnection cnn = db_connection())
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
         cmd.CommandText = ".....";
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
         using(MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            return login.HasRows;
    }
}
```

No need to close explicitly the connection because the exit from the using block automatically closes the connection and disposes the instance freeing the resources kept by the connection both locally and on the server.

Of course, when you need to query again the database the same pattern should be used.

Comment: upvote for `using block` I don't know why I don't see more people using this when utilizing db connections

Comment: Each time the database is accessed, you open and close it once to validate the user and then open and close it again to access the data?   While that works, it will be slower than it has to be.

Comment: @SteveWellens no, of course you validate the user just one time (or if you want a re-check to allow access to some kind of sensitive data) After the validation, everytime you need to access the database, you use this pattern. Connection Pooling allows reuse of connections with improved performances so you should always close the connection

Comment: @Steve - I disapprove of a 'one solution fits all problems approach'.  Sometimes your suggestion is the way to go, however if this is a single user application (and from the connection string it looks like it is) leaving the connection open is better.  Because it is simpler and faster.

Comment: OK good luck with that, it is just code not a death or life choice. However remember me when you get misterious error messages about resources leaks and you don't know why they happen. Or when a customer calls and talks about 'too many connections open' or... well I think I have made my point clear.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you validate the login, you are closing the connection:

```
if (login.Read())
{
    connect.Close();
    return true;
}
else
{
     connect.Close();
     return false;
 }
```

Either leave the connection open, or reopen it.   Most people leave it open for speed and simplicity.

Comment: Leaving a connection open and not disposed is a **big big** mistake.

Comment: So edit            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to server!");
            } If i add a value to textbox and passwordbox i get the error:Additional information: Connection must be valid and open

Comment: @Steve - Right, when you are done with the connection close it (which also disposes it).

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your command about your connection object. Add the connection parameter to command
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(connect );